# how to give permissions to a new user

Tags: linux, nginx

I've been struggling with this for a while, I was working with a user `userOne`, and then I decided to created a new user `userTwo`, once I did that with

`./configure --user=userTwo --group=userTwo --with-http_ssl_module` the `userOne` lost all the permissions, everytime I try to restart the nginx or whatever I try, I get this

`userOne@ANKH:/usr/local/nginx/conf$ sudo cp ~/capilleira/*.conf . && sudo service nginx restart
/etc/init.d/nginx: You don't have permissions to execute nginx.`

or

`mretana@mretana:~/Documents/Projects/capilleiraclickandgamblebackend/nginx$ sudo scp *.conf userOne@192.168.1.251:~/capilleira
c0pt@192.168.1.251's password: 
scp: /home/userOne/capilleira/backend_proxy_pass.conf: Permission denied
scp: /home/userOne/capilleira/expires.conf: Permission denied
scp: /home/userOne/capilleira/gzip.conf: Permission denied
scp: /home/userOne/capilleira/nginx.conf: Permission denied
scp: /home/userOne/capilleira/protect_system_files.conf: Permission denied
scp: /home/userOne/capilleira/security.conf: Permission denied
scp: /home/userOne/capilleira/ssl.conf: Permission denied`

and in my config file `user  userTwo userTwo;`, so what can I do to give permissions to both users ?

Comment: Wait, you're trying to add permissions by changing the user that nginx runs as?

Comment: something like that, I just add that new user and now I am getting a ```403 Forbidden``` error in the browser, and lots of errors in the terminal. The main user ```userOne``` lost all the permissions, I want that user back with all the rights, and also I want to give all the permissions to ```userTwo``` @EEAA

Answer (score 2):

OK, you are going about this in the wrong way.

First, why are you compiling nginx? Unless you have very specific requirements, it's not advised to do this. Instead, use the nginx package from your distro's package repository.

Second, you don't add permissions by *recompiling your application*. You do it by manipulating the ownership and file mode of the files and directories in question.

If you wanted to give `userTwo` permissions to `/home/userOne/capilleira/`, then add `userTwo` to the group who owns that directory and then make sure that the group owner has write access.

Comment: how I figure out the group who owns that directory ?

Comment: Sorry, we don't spoon-feed here. We expect that you're a professional sysadmin and that you are able to do a bit of research on your own. I'd recommend a web server for "linux file permissions tutorial" or the like.